# Selenium - how to select each text object (one by one)

Tags: selenium

Im using selenium in Katalon.

I wonder how I can select two text object under "h3" tag.

And I want to select them one by one.

This is the html:

[image: html code]

This is the code Im having right now

I have tried some options, and commented them out

And I have this loop cause I have some phone number blocks that I want to loop through.

Hope someone can help me :)

```
def phoneNumbersBlock = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//li[@class='ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-valid ng-star-inserted']"))
    def phoneNumbersBlockCount = phoneNumbersBlock.size()
    println("PhoneNumber count: "+phoneNumbersBlockCount)
    
    for (int i = 0; i < phoneNumbersBlockCount; i++) {
    
    //def phoneNumber = phoneNumbersBlock[i].findElement(By.tagName("h3")).getText();
    //def phoneNumber = phoneNumbersBlock[i].findElement(By.xpath("//h3//text")).getText();
    //def phoneNumber = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//li[@class='ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-valid ng-star-inserted']//h3/text()[1]"))
    //def phoneNumber = phoneNumbersBlock[i].findElements(By.tagName("h3"))[0].getText();
    def phoneNumber = phoneNumbersBlock[i].findElement(By.cssSelector("div > h3:nth-child(1)")).getText();
            println("PhoneNumber "+i+": "+phoneNumber)
        
    def phoneNumberText = phoneNumbersBlock[i].findElement(By.tagName("h3")).getText();
    println("PhoneNumber Text "+i+": "+phoneNumberText)
    }
```

The console output gives me this right now:

PhoneNumber count: 3

PhoneNumber 0: 070265895 (SLWEB AUTOTEST)

PhoneNumber Text 0: 070265895 (SLWEB AUTOTEST)

Answer (score 0):

This is a text within a single node (element). Based on everything I know about elements location, there is no way to understand, is the text partiated, or it's a singe string.

I can suggest only trying to locate the parrent element and execute js

```
WebElement parent = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//h3/.."));
String innerHtml = ((JavaScriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("return arguments[0].innerHTML", parent);
```

The output will contain pure html, you'll need to split it on parts and extract the content using String methods.